# extract time and date from field qlikview

Tags: time, transformation, extract, qlikview

i have this kind of data

```
Check_in

18/11/2019 10:32:01
18/11/2019 10:12:28
18/11/2019 09:32:57
18/11/2019 09:28:58
18/11/2019 09:28:53
```

now i want to extract date and time from this field

i.e.

```
date                   time

18/11/2019   10:32:01
```

i try this in script but this does not working

Time(Fromtime) as check_in

when i try to format date on excel this shows like this. sames dates are converted and some are not

[image]

files

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xnxaprguz7x3fua/zooho%20dash.qvw?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3yb2zm7plaf9o6p/excell_timein_sheet.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The main trick here is that you want to use DATE#(), TIME#(), TIMESTAMP#() because you know the format of the inputs and want to force Qlik to recognise them as dates and times

```
CHECK_INS:
load *,
     date(floor(TIMESTAMP)) as DATE2,
     time(TIMESTAMP) as TIME2
;
load *,
     date#(subfield(check_in,' ',1),'DD/MM/YYYY') as DATE,
     time#(subfield(check_in,' ',2),'hh:mm:ss') as TIME,
     Timestamp#(check_in,'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss') as TIMESTAMP
;
```

The subfield() is to split the Date and Time section based on the location of the space.
The other option is to first TIMESTAMP#() the whole timestamp and then use the date() and time() functions. You need the floor() to remove the time portion from the dates otherwise you'll see what look like multiple entries for the same date, but they are just timestamps formatted as dates so still remember their time portion.